# Timestamp comparison doesn't work on TIMESTAMP field

Tags: mysql

I have a database column called `time`

```
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But when I run the following query using `PDO`:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :days DAY))
```

It throws the following exception:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1555980012' for column 'time' at row 1

I don't understand why this is happening, could any one please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP function in your where clause to convert date to number.
This should work with no issue:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `time` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :days DAY)
```

Comment: But it works fine on another table, `SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE search=:search AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :limit HOUR` <- this query works perfectly fine on another table! I don't understand why is this happening